# abort() has been called - R6010 - multithreading server cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, server

Im trying to open a multithreading server, that can handle more than 1 client at the same time.
What's happening is the first client connects, the server prints "in", which means it entered the interact function, and after the recv of the message of the client, it prints "muffins".

in short:
client 1 connects - "in" is printed in server window (server's waiting for message from client 1)

client 2 connects - nothing is printed

client 1 sends message to server

"muffins" is printed, then the "in" of the client 2 connection is printed.

what should happen is:
client 1 connects - "in" is printed in server window

client 2 connects - "in is printed in server window

I've come to realize that the server waits for the first thread to finish, before handling the second client's thread, and that's because of the join() in the main function.
If i remove the join(), i get a runtime error - abort has been called (R6010)
any idea how to solve this?

this is my class Server, where the actual communication is done:

```
typedef struct addrinfo addinfo;

class Server
{
 private:
     WSADATA _wsaData;
     int _iResult;
     SOCKET _ListenSocket;
     addrinfo* _result;
     addrinfo _hints;
     int _iSendResult;
     char _recvbuf[BUF_LEN];
     int _recvbuflen;
     std::vector<SOCKET> _ClientSockets;

 public:
     Server();
     bool Setup();
     bool CreateSocket();
     bool Bind();
     bool Listen();
     bool Accept();
     bool Send();
     bool Shutdown();
     ~Server();
 };

Server::Server()
{
    _ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    _ClientSockets.push_back(INVALID_SOCKET);
    _result = NULL;
    _recvbuflen = BUF_LEN;
}


bool Server::Setup() {
    _iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &_wsaData);
    if (_iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << _iResult << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&_hints, sizeof(_hints));
    _hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    _hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    _hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    _hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    _iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &_hints, &_result);
    if (_iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo failed with error: " << _iResult << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Server::CreateSocket() {
    _ListenSocket = socket(_result->ai_family, _result->ai_socktype, _result->ai_protocol);
    if (_ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "socket failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        freeaddrinfo(_result);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool Server::Bind() {
    _iResult = bind(_ListenSocket, _result->ai_addr, (int)_result->ai_addrlen);
    if (_iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "bind failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        freeaddrinfo(_result);
        closesocket(_ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(_result);
    return true;
}

bool Server::Listen() {
    _iResult = listen(_ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (_iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "listen failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(_ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Server::Accept() {
    _ClientSockets.push_back(accept(_ListenSocket, NULL, NULL));
    if (_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1] == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "accept failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(_ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Server::Send() {
    _iResult = recv(_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1], _recvbuf, _recvbuflen, 0);
    std::cout << "muffins" << endl;
    if (_iResult > 0) {
        _iSendResult = send(_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1], "Accepted", strlen("Accepted"), 0);
        if (_iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "send failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1]);
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (_iResult == 0)
        std::cout << "Connection closing..." << std::endl;
    else  {
        std::cout << "recv failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1]);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Server::Shutdown() {
    _iResult = shutdown(_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1], SD_SEND);
    if (_iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "shutdown failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1]);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    closesocket(_ClientSockets[_ClientSockets.size() - 1]);
    WSACleanup();

    return true;
}

Server::~Server()
{
}
```

this is the main file:

```
void interact(Server* server);

int main() {
    Server* server = new Server();
    server->Setup();
    server->CreateSocket();
    server->Bind();
    server->Listen();
    while (1) {
        socket->Accept();
        std::thread trd(interact, server);
        trd.join();
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    server->Shutdown();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void interact(Server* server) {

    std::cout << "in" << std::endl;
    server->Send();
}
```

Comment: What is the very first line of your program for? Why are you creating a thread and then waiting for it to finish? It means that you will never have this thread and the new one running in parallel. What happens if you simply don't start a thread but run the code directly?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If I dont start a thread, and just call interact() directly, it functions in the exact same fashion.
I want it to open a new thread for each client, but not wait for the thread to finish, I want them to run in parallel.

Comment: If it also breaks if you don't start a thread, then you can remove the threading code and thus further circle in on the root of the problem. BTW: Looking at this, the threads handling client connections should only receive that connection handle, not the whole `Server` instance. Not sharing this big object between threads makes it less likely that you have race conditions from the lack of synchronization. That said, where exactly does it fail? Add debug output for that. Further, don't use output and `bool`s (which you don't check!) to signal errors, use `throw runtime_error("error message")`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It fails when it gets to the recv in the Send() function.
I believe we aren't supposed to use handles here.
Also I didn't say it breaks if i dont use threading, only that it doesn't respond immediately to each client

Comment: Don't interpret the term "handle" too strictly, e.g. `SOCKET` is a handle. If your handler thread only receives that handle, it should have enough info to respond to the client.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt So you mean, change the Send() function to get 2 SOCKET parameters, and work on that? Or maybe just get the listen socket and the client socket from the Server and recv/send with those, outside of the class?

Comment: No, because you don't have a `Send()` function! What you have is a memberfunction, and a memberfunction always receives the object it is invoked on as implicit, hidden parameter called `this`. What you should do instead is have the `Accept()` function return a new "connection", which you then pass to the thread for handling. This "connection" could be a `SOCKET` now, but it could also become its own class later.